# Leonardo side view problem

Tags: prompt-design, leonardo.ai, prompt-configuration

I want to ask anyone if they encountered this problem. Whatever I do, it always generate character, that is facing the camera, meaning from the front view.
I want to make 2d character from sideview.
This is the prompt that I used and it throws only profile pictures from front:
"Imagine an anime-style character design for a 2D platformer game. The character is based on Red Riding Hood and should be depicted from a sideview perspective. The color scheme should primarily include red, pink, and black. The overall style should be anime-inspired, with attention to detail."
Thanks anyone